# How to create a network diagram using UML?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, uml

I need some help, how do i create a network diagram using UML? I am new to UML and want to create a network diagram that will show an infrastructure of any web host application. How can i achieve this by using UML?

Comment: There is no "network diagram" in UML, if you want to show hosts linked by network you can use a deployment diagram where hosts are represented by nodes

Comment: @bruno deployment diagram not network?

Comment: what you mean ? I don't understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no network diagram in UML.  But if you want to represent how system components fit in an infrastructure of interconnected processing nodes at runtime, you may consider a [deployment diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram).

These [diagrams](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-deployment-diagram/) are straightforward:  you need to identify the nodes that are involved,  how they are related, and then map the artefacts of your components to the nodes.  This requires however a very good knowledge of your system structure and components.

Where it may become tricky is the level of granularity, especially now, in a world of virtualized servers and containers.  At what level of precision will you represent your nodes, which can be nested (e.g. one cloud platform that itself is made of several containers,  which may host different run-time processes for different components.

***Additional remark:** I shouldn't say this on an UML tag, but your question suggests that you do not know yet very well the structure of the hosted system.  In this case you can only make a very simple deployment diagram with little value added.  If you're more focused on the infrastructure, you may then consider the [C4 model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4_model) alternative: it allows to represent the infrastructure and the generic big blocks in a more flexible and less formal way. You may then let the component-sketches emerge in such an infrastructure.  C4 is complementary to UML which is then used for the detailed component decomposition and the behavioral modelling. You may then revisit the deployment model in a later stage, once the system structure is known with the sufficient details.*